# How to auto refresh table contents in EXT.js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having a table whose contents(name and status) i'm trying to refresh every 1 min in such a way that the status should change from 'schedule' to 'active' to 'running' w/o having user manually refresh it.
here is the js:

```
    $cls.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
        useTemplate: true,
        directFn: Service('getRecordService').getRecord,
        fields: [
              {
                name : 'name',
                column: {
                    header: "Name",
                    renderer: function (record) {
                      return name(record.data.name);
                    },
                }
            },

            {
                name : 'status',
                column: {
                    header: "status",
                    renderer: function (record) {
                      return status(record.data.status);
                    },
                }
            },

        ],
        viewConfig: {
            getRecord: function (){
                ///get single record info
            }
        };

    });
```

I'm not sure how can i write a function in the above snippet that will allow me to auto refresh the table contents every 1 min. Any ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: @And-y: Ext JS 3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [Ext.util.TaskRunner](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner) and the singleton [Ext.TaskMgr](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.TaskMgr).
It provides methods to start/stop task functions which are executed in a configurable interval.

With that you could try something like below.

```
var grid = ;                    // your grid instance
var store = grid.getStore();    // store of your grid, you want to reload
var refreshTask = {             // task which reloads the store each minute
    run: function() {
        store.reload();
    },
    interval: 60 * 1000 // 1 Minute
};

Ext.util.TaskRunner.start(refreshTask);
```